# SQL Server 2008: updating table columns conditionally

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, case-when

I am still quite new to SQL, so bear with me.

To simplify my question, let's say I have 2 identical person tables with attributes/fields such as ID, last_name, first_name, date_of_birth, street, city, state, zip.

I would like table 2 to be updated based on what is in table 1, but I would like to retain data in table 2 that has been added since the last time I refreshed from table 1.

It boils down to two logical tracks that I don't know how to convert into a SQL query:

1. Update columns in table 2 that are null
2. (This is the one I don't know how to do) Update columns in table 2, including overwriting existing data, except when the override from the corresponding column in table 1 would override data in table 2 with null values.

Thanks in advance

### update

Ok, so the 2 tables start out identical:

[Person table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTFOg.png)

Then, users will be updating table 2, while table 1 will also receive an update during the same time.

Let's say the first name and middle name of ID 1 were updated in table 2, while the middle name of ID 2 was update in table 1.

[Person table changes before update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCuaV.png)

So now, I am trying to come up with an SP, that will update table 2 based on table 1 and using the logic I described above.

Every column in table 2 should be overwritten with data in the corresponding columns in table one, even if it overwrites existing data. So 'John' will become Rachel again. The exception I would like to make for this overwriting is when data in table 2 would be overwritten with a null value.

So while John will be overwritten back to Rachel, William, as the middle_name, should stay in table 2, because table 1 has a null value for that ID (ID 1)
I would post another picture of the desired output, but apparently I do not have enough reputation yet to post more than 2 links. So here is my wanted output in text

Person_2 after update

ID|last_name|first_name|middle_name

1|Addy|Rachel|William

2|Aguilar|Richard|Geoffrey

3|...

Comment: Well, I would at least add a `ModificationDate` (or `overrideDate`) in the second table, if you wanna apply a `Last time I refreshed` logic.

Comment: please explain with some sample data and show expected output'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I figured it out eventually. 
Here is what I did.

If anybody has a more efficient way of doing this, I'm all ear. Thanks.

```
SELECT Person_2.id

  ,CASE WHEN Person_2.ID=Person_1.id 
           AND Person_2.last_name IS NULL 
               THEN Person_1.last_name 

           WHEN Person_2.ID=Person_1.id 
           AND Person_2.last_name IS NOT NULL 
           AND Person_1.last_name IS NULL
               THEN Person_2.last_name

           WHEN Person_2.ID=Person_1.id 
           AND Person_2.last_name IS NOT NULL 
           AND Person_1.last_name IS NOT NULL
               THEN Person_1.last_name                   

               END AS last_name  


  ,CASE WHEN Person_2.ID=Person_1.id 
           AND Person_2.first_name IS NULL 
               THEN Person_1.first_name 

           WHEN Person_2.ID=Person_1.id 
           AND Person_2.first_name IS NOT NULL 
           AND Person_1.first_name IS NULL
               THEN Person_2.first_name

           WHEN Person_2.ID=Person_1.id 
           AND Person_2.first_name IS NOT NULL 
           AND Person_1.first_name IS NOT NULL
               THEN Person_1.first_name                   

               END AS first_name  


  ,CASE WHEN Person_2.ID=Person_1.id 
           AND Person_2.middle_name IS NULL 
               THEN Person_1.middle_name 

           WHEN Person_2.ID=Person_1.id 
           AND Person_2.middle_name IS NOT NULL 
           AND Person_1.middle_name IS NULL
               THEN Person_2.middle_name

           WHEN Person_2.ID=Person_1.id 
           AND Person_2.middle_name IS NOT NULL 
           AND Person_1.middle_name IS NOT NULL
               THEN Person_1.middle_name                   

               END AS middle_name      

FROM Person_2 
   LEFT JOIN [Person_1]  ON Person_2.id=Person_1.id
```